# Perform an action when a process has finished in PHP

Tags: php, process

I've been using this function to check if a process is running or not. (I got it from http://nsaunders.wordpress.com/2007/01/12/running-a-background-process-in-php/):

```
function Is_Process_Running($PID){

exec("ps $PID", $ProcessState); 
return(count($ProcessState) >= 2);  
}
```

My understanding of it is that the function will only return if the array $ProcessState has more than two lines in it, which it will if the process is active.

So it's thus easy to code something to perform an action whilst the process is running as below (also from above link):

```
while(is_process_running($PID))
   {
     echo(" . ");
       ob_flush(); flush();
            sleep(1);
   }
```

But then what's the best way to do perform an action when the process has completed? I tried:

```
while(! is_process_running($PID))
```

but this doesn't work, I think because it only goes through the loop once. Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put the code to be performed *after* the loop:

```
// Process is still running
while (is_process_running($PID))
{
  // wait
}

// Process is no longer running
do_stuff_afterwards();
```

If you need to branch depending on whether the process is running at all in the first place, you can wrap the entire thing in a `if (is_process_running($PID))` conditional.

Comment: gosh I really didn't think it'd be that easy, thanks a lot! I didn't realize though, this makes the php page pause as it waits for the while loop - which isn't ideal for me. Have to think of another solution, maybe feed the PID to a bash script or something. Cheers!

Comment: @Jingo: PHP is only ever single-threaded. If you need to wait for an event, you will probably have to look into some event-based callback system. I'm not familiar with any for PHP of the top off my head, but I'm by no means an expert, and chances are that such a solution exists. You could always ask a separate question about "asynchronous waiting for a process to terminate in PHP" or so...

Answer (score 1):

Check out the PCNTL functions (http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pcntl.php). Depending on what your trying to do, this library may be very helpful. There are some code samples on the individual function pages... check out pcntl_wait();